# C# Program with Admin permission is not starting at windows startup

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0

I have developed a program with admin Permission (UAC) and also done Registry entry using following Code

```
 Registry.SetValue(
   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
   "SyncData-TPSS",
   Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()
 );
```

to start Program at Startup. But because of UAC it is not starting at windows Stratup. I can't remove UAC.

IF I remove UAC and access Registry values then it is throwing Exception Access Denied

Any idea to do this ?

Comment: How could UAC affect a program running on -startup-? (As opposed to on login)

Comment: If i remove UAC then it is running on startup but not getting values from Registry. Because it throws Exception Access to Registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\syncData-TPSS"

Comment: Are you sure you mean *startup*?

Comment: Hmmm... ok; interesting. Another question: How do you know it's not being run when UAC is on?

Comment: When app will run , it will open a WinForm for user Entry.

Comment: Ummm... then it's not running on startup. It's running on login.

Answer (score 0):

Build it as a windows service, and when installing the service make sure to choose a user that has admin rights.